# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [5] Cannot get cloud region in global job (while deploying node js code)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am receiving above error while deploying nodejs express code on Google cloud app engine. Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue and the Google Cloud Platform team has mitigated it. Now, you should be able to deploy your App Engine. Can you please try it and let me know if this is working now?